# Reading a block of data into a file buffer call to function returns next char

Tags: c, linux

I need to use this function to read a block of data into the file buffer and do so efficiently. A call to my function needs to either return the next character from the buffer or read  a new block of data and return that first character from that new block. Here is what I have so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
int get_next_char(int fd)   {

    static char file_buffer[FILE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    static int next;
    static int i= 0;

    while((next = read( fd,&file_buffer, FILE_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        // next equals number of chars actually read from fd
        while(i < next) i++;
    }

    if( next  == -1 || next== '\0') {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        return file_buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could just use fgetc(3).

Comment: I have to use systems calls otherwise yes fgetc would work.

Comment: My questions is how do i get my function to read the next char efficiently? Because when I run this I am only reading a single char byte at a time from the file descriptor.

Comment: Not sure how to answer this because **(a)** You have not asked a question, and **(b)** I can see a problem with just about every line of code.

Comment: What my functions is overall supposed to do is the implementation of fgetc. But yeah I am a C beginner. All it is doing is causing a seg fault and I guess my question is why?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own internal buffered version of `fgetc` using system calls for this. Something trivial would be the following:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int fgetc_impl(FILE* fp) {
    static FILE *pBuffered;
    static char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    static int start = 0, end = 0;

    // conditions under which you'll need to make a syscall to read into
    // the local buffer. Either a new file descriptor has been presented, or
    // we've read to the end of the local buffer and need to re-read a new chunk into it
    if (pBuffered != fp || start == end) {
        pBuffered = fp;
        end = read((int)fp, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
        start = 0;

        // mask the syscall failure and report it as an EOF, change this behaviour if you want.
        if (end < 0) {
            end = 0; 
        }
    }

    // return EOF if the syscall to read failed, or couldn't read any more data from the file descriptor.
    return end == 0 ? EOF : buffer[start++];
}
```

Simple usage would be the following:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
int c = 0;
while ( (c = fgetc_impl(fp)) != EOF ) {
    printf("%c", (char)c);
}
fclose(fp);
```